# How to pass a parameter from Java method to a div in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a class where I have a method that displays data. Each data displayed has a link. When I click on the link I want to pass parameter to a specific div in a JSP page.

eg: The method in my java class has code like:

```
output += "<td width=\"30%\" " + colorCode + " >&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
          "<a href=\"testselect.jsp?testclass="+testName+"\">" + testName + "</a>";
```

And index.jsp has a div:

```
<div id="testselect" title="Basic try">
</div>
```

How do I call the div with id testselect from when the link is clicked and how do I pass the parameter also?

Comment: The question is not clear. class you meant Java class or HTML CSS class? If it's Java class method you can return some values to JSP and set some values in div. But I don't get the idea of clicking the link. Can you please explain the question?

Comment: Ok , let me explain more. I have a jsp page index.jsp that calls a method abc() in java clss. This method abc() iterates and creates a table which has several links in it. Now I want that when someone click this link which is generated in the java class method to pass a parameter to a specific div in index.jsp ... Hope this helps

Comment: "Pass a parameter to a div"? You don't pass parameters to a div. Do you mean you want to make a request and fill the div with the results of a new request, e.g., simple Ajax?

Comment: yes. I am new to this and have never used ajax before. Can you please give me some example which can explain me more. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Search the web, there are essentially unlimited tutorials and examples. I'd consider using a JavaScript support library, e.g., jQuery, Zepto, or any of many others.